# Time Picker Difference between current and Time Picker Time Android Alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am creating a simple Time Picker Dialog and when user set time I am storing that time in a Calendar instance.

```
 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) 
 {
    tpCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    tpCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, i);
    tpCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, i1);
    tpCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    updateReminder();
 }
```

And calculating difference in updateReminder() method

```
private void updateReminder() 
{
    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diff = tpCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - currTime;
    long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);

    Intent reminderIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderReceiver.class);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)     getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, diff,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, reminderIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
```

And bassed on difference I am setting an alarm. I am getting correct difference in Millis (diff variable). But problem is that after the alarm is set and no matter what difference is set, it notifies after 5 seconds.

In broadcast receivers I just create a notification.
I will appreciate any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing something like when I made my AlarmClock (after TimePicked):

```
String[] arrTime = time.split(":");
int hour = Integer.parseInt(arrTime[0]);
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(arrTime[1]);
    GregorianCalendar calendar = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.DATE));
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

Comment: So you just set new time to calendar and pass it to alarmManager?

Comment: ok, I thought you need to pass difference between two times. Thanks it worked.

Comment: @RahulBhavani glad it helped, happy codings)